# How to integrate react-native-msal with an expo managed app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, msal.js

I'm trying to integrate react-native-msal with an expo managed app, I keep getting this error when I try to initialize the public client application instance:

```
Error initializing the pca, check your config. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPublicClientApplication' of null]
```

I followed these directions (exactly as they're written) https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/tree/14ecbf8159dd0855c4b2137e933597a1d2c4649f for the Expo set up.

Here is my App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import PublicClientApplication from "react-native-msal";
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "my_client_id",
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations'
    }
};

export default function App() {
  const pca = new PublicClientApplication(config);

  async function initialize() {    
    try {
      await pca.init();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initializing the pca, check your config.', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initialize();
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When I console log pca after declaring it as a new PublicClientApplication instance, this is what  I get in the console

```
{
  "config": {
    "auth": {
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations", 
        "clientId": "my_client_id"
    }
  }, 
  "isInitialized": false
}
```

I'm not seeing an init() method on pca, what am I doing wrong?

I've tried using different authorities in the config object and nothing has worked. The only thing  that I can think of that would be causing this is that the only step I couldn't do in the react-native-msal setup is run "npx pod-install", which after searching through stack overflow, it seems like you can't run that command with an expo app because expo removes all of the react native code. Thoughts?

Comment: I've been looking at the setup guides here: https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/blob/master/docs/android_setup.md and https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/blob/master/docs/expo_setup.md

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sarahm16: were you able to sort this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Expo Dev Client in your app and then try it out. See here for Expo Dev client - https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/introduction/#what-is-expo-dev-client